# Powershell error when invoking another script

Tags: powershell

I have two scripts that run fine as seperate scripts, but when I invoke one from the other then I get this error message:

> Exception Name: System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException
>   Exception Type:
>   Exception Message: Exception calling "Open" with "3" argument(s): "Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Data Report\'.

The script being called is moving files from "D:\Data Report\ to another folder in the D:\ directory.

I only get this error when I run the script below. Any ideas?

```
try
{
    $folder = "D:\Data Report\" # Enter the root path you want to monitor.
    $filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here.
    #$scriptPath = {D:\"file_transfer.ps1"}

    # In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if required.
    $watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}

    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
        $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
        $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
        $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
        Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green

        #Call the file_transfer.ps1 script
        #Invoke-Expression $scriptPath
        Invoke-Expression D:\file_transfer.ps1
    }

} # end of try
catch  #Catch any fatel errors and send an email with description
{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
    $ErrorName = $_.Exception.GetType().FullName

    $ExceptionBody = @"
    Exception Name: $ErrorName
    Exception Type: $FailedItem
    Exception Message: $ErrorMessage
    "@
    Send-MailMessage  -SmtpServer "server.com" -From "no-replies@company.com" -To "admin@company.com" -Subject "Fatel Error with Monitor Script" -Body $ExceptionBody
} # end of catch
```

#

@TheMadTechnician Here is the other script that works on its own.

```
try
{
$path="D:\Data Report\" 
$Miscdir="D:\TEST\Data\Misc"
$dataFolder = "D:\Data Report\*"
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path ($path) -ErrorAction Stop
$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'

# enumerate the items array
foreach ($item in $items)
{

      # if the item is NOT a directory, then process it.
     if ($item.Attributes -ne "Directory")
     {
           #Write-Host $item.Name
           $filePath = $path+$item.name


}
else  #send email and exit without running.
{
    Write-Host "$filePath is a directory"
     Exit
}

function isFileLocked([string]$LockedPath) {
$file=$filePath
$oFile = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $LockedPath
# Make sure the path is good
if ((Test-Path -Path $LockedPath) -eq $false)
{
  echo "Bad Path"
  return $false
}
      #Try opening file
  $oStream = $oFile.Open([System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, [System.IO.FileShare]::None)
  if ($oStream)
  {
    echo "Got valid stream so file must not be locked"
    $oStream.Close()
    #Pick   ID from file name
    $ ID = ($item.name.Split("_")[0])
    Write-Host $ ID

        $listcsv = import-csv d:\number.csv
        foreach($number in $listcsv){

        $UNCNumber = $number.UNCNumber
        #Write-Host $UNCNumber
        ANCNumber = $number.NoseNumber
        #Write-Host ANCNumber
        ANCNumber = $number.NoseNumber

        if ($ ID -eq $UNCNumber)

   {
        #Check/create  ID folder
    ANCNumberdir="D:\TEST\Data\ANCNumber"
    Write-Host ANCNumber
    if (!(Test-Path ANCNumberdir))
     { mkdir ANCNumberdir }

     Echo "Nose number found the csv file ANCNumber" 
      $ IDdir = ANCNumber
          Write-Host " id from csv file $ ID" }
          }

#Check/create App id folder/system
   #Pick App ID from file name
    $AppID=($item.name.Split("_")[1])
    Write-Host $AppID


        $Appiddir="ANCNumberdir\$AppID"
       if (!(Test-Path $Appiddir))
     { mkdir $Appiddir 
         Write-Host $Appiddir
        }


   Move-Item ($filePath) $Appiddir
     return $false
  } # end if ($oStream)
  else 
  {

   echo "InValid stream so file is locked"
    return $true

if (!(Test-Path $Miscdir))
          { 
      mkdir $Miscdir 
      Write-Host $Miscdir
          }             
     Move-Item $path"*" $Miscdir 
  }
}# end of function
isFileLocked($filePath)

} 


# Send an email if the script ran but a file didn't get moved out of the Data Report folder    

     If (Test-Path $dataFolder)
     {
     $DataNumbers = (get-childitem $dataFolder | ?{!($_.PSIsContainer)}).Count
      }

# check how many files are in our Misc folder and email

    $MiscNumbers = (get-childitem $miscdir | ?{!($_.PSIsContainer)}).Count
    If ($MiscNumbers -gt 0)
    {
    }

    } # end of try
    catch  #Catch any fatel errors and send an email with description
    {
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
    $ErrorName = $_.Exception.GetType().FullName 

    $ExceptionBody = @"
    Exception Name: $ErrorName
    Exception Type: $FailedItem 
    Exception Message: $ErrorMessage 
"@
     } # end of catch

    finally
    {

    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `Invoke-Expression` to run the other script: why not just call it directly (and pass parameters for any data it needs from this script). But without including full information from the error (what script line?) we're guessing. Suggestion: remove the `try/catch` to see full details of the error until it normally works.

Comment: What part of the script is causing the error? The line and character number should be provided in the error message (`At line:# char:#`). In any case, the error message seems pretty straightforward: The path `'D:\Data Report\'` is not accessible. Does the script run under an account that doesn't have permissions to access this path? Try adding `Test-Path $folder` immediately after defining **$folder**.

Comment: Richard -- I thought that was what I was doing. How else do you "just call it directly"?

Comment: The error is coming from the script being called. It does not have an error when I run it on it's own, but when its called from this script it sends the error message to my email. Everything works, it just sends me the error email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it is doing this but if the first script runs and it doesn't find a file in the $path then it would throw the "Exception calling "Open" with "3" argument(s): "Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Data Report\'." error. So I don't know why but when the first scripts calls the 2nd script then it thinks its running and a file is not there. 
So I put in a:
     if (Test-Path -Path "$path*") {
     working code
     }
     else
      {
      exit
      }

Answer (score 0):

I was about to comment, but I think that would end up too long and hard to read. As Richard said, it seems that your issue is likely coming from using `Invoke-Expression` when all you want to do is run the other script. There's two basic ways to do this (and many more considerably more complicated ways), so I'll run them down for you real fast.

Use the Call Operator, `&`, to run the script. It would be done as such:

```
& D:\file_transfer.ps1
```

It's that simple. That will run the other script, and it will run autonomously of this first script.

The second way is to dot source it, which is very similar to using the Call Operator except that it runs the script in the same session so the other script would have access to the variables and what not that you already have declared. From the looks of your script it isn't needed, but it usually doesn't hurt from my experience. The way you would do that is:

```
. D:\file_transfer.ps1
```

Hopefully that clears up running the script without using the `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet.

**Bonus info!** When replying to somebody's comment put an `@` in front of their name and it will show them that they have a message.

Comment: Thank you @TheMadTechnician. So I'm using the & D:\file_transfer.ps1 now. I'm still getting the same error message. "Exception Message: Exception calling "Open" with "3" argument(s): "Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Data Report\'." " when I run it from the script above. I've taken the catch/try out of it as well. When I run the file_transfer.ps1 on its own it is perfect.

Comment: The script generating the error is your file transfer script right? Why don't you show us the relevant code from that script?